# C++ code on server, running on client machine

Tags: c++, database, client, client-side

Is it possible to write C++ code to interface with a server, but to be executed on client side, but on the browser instead of native?

Like, for example, imagine using open source classes so that you produce a file.
But because you don't want all this work to be done on the server, you run it on the browser.

So that the client gives a file or two or more as inputs, then the code runs on his machine, the final result is produced, then this file is uploaded to database on the server.

Comment: Sounds pretty much like http://boinc.berkeley.edu/ (for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple solutions when if you want to do  work on the browser, then have the results posted in a server database.

First of all, you must set up your server ready for database work. I have done this using the MEAN stack, set up a MongoDB and interfaced it with the Mongoose API.

Now, for the meat of the question, there are many examples of browsers doing intensive work. The majority of these applications thought is not C++, but it is Javascript.

If you really want to focus on C++ (like i did in the past, in the time i asked this question, wanting to make something big for college), then you could do one of the following:

*Use Google Native Client (NaCl). This is a sandbox for running compiled C and C++ code in the browser efficiently and securely, independent of the user’s operating system.
*Maybe you should want to check out Emscripten, which is a framwork for translating C and C++ code to jaascript. This way, you can have your C or C++ binaries that worked, and have them translated to Javascript, in order to have them work in the browser too.

Answer (score 0):

please see google native client project. http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/

Answer (score 0):

This is strange question.

You can prepare binaries that do task that you want done on client side and make server send proper binary to client when asked for it. Client then runs this binary and returns results to server.

It is possible if you know configurations of client machines (binaries must work on them). Also it have to be some security layer implemented - you don't want to allow every binary run on client (imagine man-in-the-middle attack when some malicious code is run on client).

Answer (score 0):

I think your request contradicts with the idea behind server-side programming. The main purpose in using server-side programs is to make use of infrastructural components like database, network, etc. in a controlled manner. (The most typical usage of server-side applications are web sites with server side coding like JSP and ASP.)

Since servers are machines that are to be kept secure, a remote application should not be permitted to make changes or access filesystem freely. If you want to do changes on a server like doing database operations or reading/writing files, you should use applications that run on the server or provide interfaces like web services or web sites to remote client applications.